# Как развернуть веб-приложение на хостинге?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Написал серверную часть используя MongoDB,Express.js,Mongoose,потом написал клиентскую часть на React,Redux. Сервер запускаю через команды mongod,mongo,nodemon на локальной машине и как мне теперь допустим развернуть это на хостинге или что для этого нужно сделать?Хотелось бы знать как это работает.

Comment: Тупой вопрос, ты случано не делаешь мод Петры Реборн?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может я не так понял твой вопрос, но:

1 - купить VPS (я люблю ubuntu, поэтому рекомендовал бы брать данную ОС для сервака)
2 - установить MongoDB на сервер
3 - установить дополнительные вещи, которые ты установил на свой комп. Типо React(Могу ошибаться)
4 - Перекинуть проект на сервер через FTP (с помощью FileZilla, как вариант)
5 - запустить через командную строку файл (использовать команду `screen`. Это позволит продолжить файлу работать на сервере после закрытия терминала/командной строки

Надеюсь, это тебе поможет